# Javascript Inputfield?

Tags: javascript

Any solution for fieldinput validation? If someone chooses the first option/value="", it goes false. Here is my html:

```
<div class="fieldinput" id="disney">
                <label for="disney">Disney Character</label>
            <select name="disney">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="mickey">Mickey Mouse</option>
                <option value="mini">Mini Mouse</option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

My javascript

```
function validate() {
        var errMsg = "";
    var result = true;


    if (disney == "") { 
    errMsg += "An option must be selected.\n"; 
    }

if (errMsg != "") {
        alert (errMsg);
        result = false;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

anyone could help? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: you are not actually getting the value for id disney

Comment: We need to see more code, and a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U shd use:

```
var disney= document.getElementsByName('disney')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
HTML:

```
<div class="fieldinput" id="disney">
    <label for="disney">Disney Character</label>
    <select name="disney">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option value="mickey">Mickey Mouse</option>
        <option value="mini">Mini Mouse</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btnSub" />
```

JS:

```
function validate(disney) {
    var result = !!disney;
    if (!result) { 
        alert("An option must be selected.\n"); 
    }
    return result;
}

var btnSub = document.getElementById("btnSub");
btnSub.onclick = function(){
    var disney = document.getElementsByName("disney")[0];
    var disVal = disney.options[disney.selectedIndex].value;
    var ret = validate(disVal);
    //ret is validate result
}
```

as:
http://jsfiddle.net/artwl/XMEwD/1/